# How to create a message with markup but without a text in telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have such replying keyboard:

```
keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Play with a bot", callback_data=str(ONE)),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Results", callback_data=str(TWO)),
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text(None, reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

It gives me such a result:

[image]

How can I get rid of the first "null" string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `None` as the Title, resulting in `null`, you should pass a message as it's required for the `send_message` and `reply_text` method:

> **text (str)** – Text of the message to be sent. Max 4096 characters after entities parsing. Also found as telegram.constants.MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH.

So, since you're required to add some text, pass it as the a extra argument to the function:

```py
keyboard = [
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton("Play with a bot", callback_data='a'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Results", callback_data='b'),
    ]
]
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
update.message.reply_text('How can I help?', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

[image]

---

As described in my comment, sending a separate message also requires some text

Comment: is there a way to reply with markup without any text?

Comment: Yea, the easiest way is to send a normal message, and add any 'reply-id' if needed. This will prevent the `reply_text` to require a title.

Comment: I've updated my answer @KenenbekArzymatov, apparently, some text is always required while sending a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an inline keyboard without text or any type of media supported by Telegram (photos, videos, audios etc). If instead you only want to update the inline keyboard without changing the message content, use the [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) method. This will update the inline keyboard leaving the original message intact.